# How do I add 3rd Party maven repository?

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

I am using sonatype nexus 2.5.1.

I have uploaded some artifacts to the 3rd party repository. But my maven build fails..

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project server: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.farheap.jsi:server:ejb:3.33.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failure to find net.jakubholy.testing:dbunit-express:jar:1.3.2 in
>   http://nexus.foo.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was
>   cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are fo rced
>   -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

I have this in my local settings.xml

```
<mirror>
<id>nexus</id>
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
<url>http://nexus.foo.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```

And in my Nexus I have setup the Public repository to have the 3rd party repository in the "Available Repositories".

I can find the artifact in the 3rd Party repository in Nexus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> And in my Nexus I have setup the Public repository to have the 3rd party
>   repository in the "**Available Repositories**"

The "Available Repositories" are the one that are *available to be added to your group*. In other words, it shows the repositories that are *not* part of your group. You should move the 3rd party repository to the "Ordered Group Repositories" to make it part of your group.

Not a very intuitive UI section imo.